# How to eliminate white spaces at the bottom of the screen while using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am using RecyclerView and Constraint layout for RecyclerView Item. 
I am using two Views in RecyclerView. 
1) ItemViewHolder
2) FooterViewHolder
Below is my code for FooterViewHolder layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/world_credits_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_1_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/world_credits_description"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_2_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description_1_text_view"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cost_1_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$10"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.226"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description_2_text_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cost_2_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$20"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cost_1_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description_2_text_view"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cost_3_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$30"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cost_2_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description_2_text_view"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_credits_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Credits"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cost_1_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/rate_category_details_list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/add_credits_button"
       />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is a code for ItemViewHolder layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/package_name_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Package Name"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/start_guideline"
    />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/start_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/package_name_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/package_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscription_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag_1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/package_description" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag_2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/flag_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/package_description"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag_3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/flag_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/package_description"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/show_multiple_countries"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/package_description"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/flag_3"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/validity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/flag_1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.028" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activate_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/nexge_blue"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/validity_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.038" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/first_divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/or_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/or_text_view"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/or_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Or"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activate_button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below code is for RecyclerView,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/show_offer_details_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_record_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/header_view" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sometime if I one or two rows are displayed, then while scrolling half of the screen is scrolling.
1) When setting FooterView of RecyclerView,  constraint layout height to wrap content, Listview displays only one item.
That's really very bad. Please Anybody help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

change your Recyclerview constraint layout height match_parent to wrap_content

Comment: I am using listview in footerview. when I changed match parent to wrap content in FooterView constraint layout. Only first item in listview is displayed.

Comment: MeanWhile if only one item is present in ItemViewHolder, then scrolling shadow is visible in half of the screen. That's really looking bad

Answer (score 0):

Change FooterViewHolder layout height to wrap contents.
The "match parent" makes it fill the whole display.

Comment: I have tried that also...That time only one item in listview is displayed remaining are hidden....Likewise if only one item present in ItemViewHolder and no footer is attached, then while try to scroll as I want screen is not scrolling but shadow in scroll is displayed half of the screen